# Remote Outlook Connect To SBS 2003

Tags: certificate, windows-sbs, outlook-anywhere

I have a client that has Windows SBS 2003. They currently have remote mail enabled, ie: mail.clientdomain.com.au/exchange prompts to accept to use the certificate, then allows them to use remote mail in the internet browser.

I am trying to setup Outlook on a remote computer to use RPC over HTTP. Is there a way to get the certificate installed on their computer so that it will work.

At the moment, I have put all the correct settings in the local mail profile, but when I try and open Outlook it is coming up with:

> There is a problem with the proxy server's security certificate. The security certificate is not from a trusted certifying authority. Outlook is unable to connec to the proxy server mail.clientdomain.com.au (Error code 8).

Please help. I have heard that there is a way to have the certificate installed via going to a website on the SBS server that will install the certificate to make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the certificate as follows:

1. Open IE on the remote computer (as administrator if you're running under UAC) and browse to the remote website address, accept the certificate as normal when prompted.
2. On the address bar, click on the certificate error message drop down, and click 'View certificate'
3. In the certificate window, click 'Install Certificate...', then follow the wizard, you must pick the option to choose where to store the certificate, and pick the 'Trusted Root Certification Authorities' section.
4. A message should confirm the successful import